# Python server is successfully handling post requests, but the file sending post requests fails somehow

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my server that is handling post requests

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class requestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

        output = ''
        output += '<html><body>'
        output += '<h1> List of Followers</h1>'
        self.wfile.write(output.encode())

    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])  # <--- Gets the size of data
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)  # <--- Gets the data itself
        print(post_data.decode('utf-8'))


def main():
    PORT = 8080
    server_address = ('localhost', PORT)
    server = HTTPServer(server_address, requestHandler)
    print("Server running on port %s" % PORT)
    server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is my client that is sending a post request

```
import requests
import sys

try:
    payload = {"name": "Me", "job" : "programmer"}
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/', json=payload)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print("WTF IS GOING ON")
    print(e)
    sys.exit(1)
```

So this is being printed out by my server console

```
Server running on port 8080
{"name": "kenny", "job": "programmer"}
```

But this is being printed out by my client console

```
WTF IS GOING ON
('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')
```

I'm not sure what this means and I've tried as much as I can before asking for help from the community. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't sending a proper response code back to the client.

Adding this in the do_POST method fixed it.

```
self.send_response(200, "OK")
self.end_headers()
```